# What functions are in the kernel of the group of functions on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ is finite?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $G$ be the group of all continuous, integrable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\ dx$ is finite under the group operation of addition. Here, when we refer to the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\ dx$, we refer to the Cauchy principal value - that is, we are actually talking about the limit $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-a}^{a}g(x)\ dx$. The first isomorphism theorem tells us that, since $G\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a homomorphism using the map $f(g)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\ dx$, then if $H=\ker G$, then $G/H\approx\mathbb{R}$.

What *is* the kernel of this group, though? We know what some of the functions in there are. Namely, we know that all the odd functions will be in $H$. Additionally, owing to the shift invariance of integration ($\int_b^af(x)\ dx=\int_{b-c}^{a-c}f(x-c)\ dx$, and thus $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\ dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x-c)\ dx$), if $\mathcal{O}(x)$ is an odd function and $c\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathcal{O}(x-c)\in H$. Finally, we know that any linear combination of these shifted odd functions will be in $H$.

What else is in there, though? Is it sufficient to say that these three classes of function compromise the entirety of the kernel, or are there other types as well? An equivalent question - if $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx=0$, then is it sufficient to say that $f$ is the linear combination of shifted odd functions? If not, how would you prove this?

Comment: Minor point: Groups don't have kernels - maps do. In your case, $f$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{R}$; So $H = \text{ker} f$, not $\text{ker}$ $G$

Comment: That $f(x)$ has principal value does not necessarily imply that $f(x+c)$ has principal value: take $f(x)=x$ and $c=1$. It is true that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x+c)dx$ if both $\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(x)dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ exist; in particular this is true when $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, i.e., $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx<\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following example:

$$g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \text { if } t < 0\\
2 & \text { if } 0 < t < 1\\
-1 & \text { if } 1 < t < 3\\
0 & \text { if } t > 3
\end{array}\right.$$

This function satisfies $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \ dx = 0$ yet it is not odd, nor is any translate of $g$ odd (you can convince yourself of this by staring at the graph; there is no way to position the origin and make the whole graph symmetric about the origin).

I would even wager that it cannot be written as the limit of odd functions either, as the space of odd functions is isomorphic to the kernel of the continuous map $f \to f(x) + f(-x)$ and is therefore closed (in particular, the limit of a sequence of odd functions should also be odd).

What *is* true about $g$ is that the "positive mass" of the function (the set $\{(x,y) : 0 \leq y \leq g(x)\}$) exactly matches the "negative mass" and therefore cancels. But this is the only stipulation; the knowledge that $g \in \operatorname{ker} f$ implies nothing about how the two masses are distributed, and they may in general be distributed very unevenly indeed.

---

This idea of positive and negative masses, however, does suggest a different characterization (parametrization?) of the elements of $\operatorname{ker} f$. Suppose $h_1$ and $h_2$ are two nonnegative functions with $\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_1(x)\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h_2(x) \ dx$. Then $g(x) = h_1(x) - h_2(x)$ is a function which satisfies $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\ dx = 0$. Conversely, beginning with any function $g$ you might define $g^+ = \max(g, 0)$ and $g^- = \max(-g, 0)$, then observe $g^+$ and $g^-$ are nonnegative functions satisfying $g = g^+ - g^-$. However, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g^+(x)\ dx$ need not exist, since you are accepting the use of Cauchy principal values, and $g^+$ need not have a finite integral for $g$ to have a finite principal value. Take $g(x) = x$, for example. Food for thought.

Comment: I agree with you in principal, but I do quickly want to point out that in your example, $g\not\in G$ because it's not continuous